# How I could bulk Rename images based on regex with php?

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove this random string from my images names, but I can't figure out the right regex pattern to use.

**Example file name:** `my-image-name-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg`

**Expected file name:** `my-image-name.jpg`

Comment: Food for thought: https://regex101.com/r/qjeiqD/1.  As along as the string to remove is just numbers or letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your string will always have the same format my-image-name-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg then you must do the following

```
 $string = 'my-image-name-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg';
   $sxplodePoint = explode('.', $string);
   $ext = $sxplodePoint[count($sxplodePoint) - 1]; //obtanin extencion
   $explodeGion =  explode('-', $string);

   $del = $explodeGion[count($explodeGion) -1];
   $newString = '';

   foreach ($explodeGion as $value) {
     if($value != $del){
        $newString = $newString. '-' .  $value;
     }
     
   }
   
   
   return trim($newString . '.' .$ext , '-');
```

A bit long code, but it will give the appropriate result if your string keeps that form

you can also use a function inside your controller

```
public function images(){

  $stringImage = 'my-image-name-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg';
  return $this->decodificator($stringImage);
```

}

```
public function decodificator($string){
   $sxplodePoint = explode('.', $string);
   $ext = $sxplodePoint[count($sxplodePoint) - 1]; //obtanin extencion
   $explodeGion =  explode('-', $string);

   $del = $explodeGion[count($explodeGion) -1];
   $newString = '';

   foreach ($explodeGion as $value) {
     if($value != $del){
        $newString = $newString. '-' .  $value;
     }
     
   }
   
   
   return trim($newString . '.' .$ext , '-');
}
```

or also if its string is an array

```
 public function imagesArray(){
   $stringImages = [
     'my-image-name-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg', 
     'my-image-name2-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg',
     'my-image-name3-fbe49f24d64ad9432d6abede3dc9f0f9.jpg'
     ];

     $newsStrings = [];
     foreach($stringImages as $stringImage){
        $newsStrings[] = $this->decodificator($stringImage);
     }

     return $newsStrings;
}
```

be careful in the shape of your string array, it may not necessarily be like my example